# how to get response only rendered javascript request

Tags: javascript, proxy, cross-domain

I have a service url that includes username password like this: **http://service.com/token?username=asd&password=123** But I can not send a request from javascript, because username and password is appearing from browser source code. So I created a Proxy page on server that sends request to service and gets token like this: **http://mydomain.com/Token/GetToken** 
I created an index page **http://mydomain.com/index.html** and javascript code sends request to Proxy page and gets token.

But somebody write a server page that sended request to my Proxy page (http://mydomain.com/Token/GetToken). And can get token.

I want to that only my rendered pages should send request to my Proxy page. Is this possible?

I am using .net mvc Project.

Comment: You can check from which host the request is coming. In http request host name will be specified. If it is not from your server simply return some 401.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is to use an existing authentication framework to protect http://mydomain.com/Token/GetToken.

If you're using a PHP backend I suggest [uLogin](http://ulogin.sourceforge.net)